# Do While condition that enable the other functions

Tags: php, mysql, web-services, if-statement, do-while

when i run the code, it will select all data from the table,when it meets the requirements of the while condition it just stop and won't continue to perform the if condition,

```
   do{
     $random = SELECT row FROM table WHERE row >= 1;
     while($ran = MySQL_fetch_array($random)){
     $rand = $ran['row'];
   }
   }while($rand == 5);
    //how can I call this function to work, 
   if(){
   `enter code here`// conditions
   }
```

Comment: pls explain properly....

Comment: What function do you mean?